# No function AWS S3 Disconnection like a PHP ftp_close() function?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ftp

I did try to find some function from AWS Dcumments.

but I have not found even same function like PHP `ftp_close()`.

A similler function is `DisassociateQueueQuickConnects()` function.

Are these Same function?

If Or not, What is better way to make this function.

ps. now I'm searching a function `FTP_put(~ , ~, $mode)`, in function of S3 `PutObject`.

Have a nice day!

Comment: You do not "connect" to S3, you issue API requests and receive responses. There is no persistent state.

Comment: Thank! @Sammitch!

morever, could you explan `Disassociates a set of quick connects from a queue.` mean?
what connection Disassociates ??

Comment: @jason It removes a list of waiting connects from a queue.  It's a feature of Amazon Connect, a product that has nothing to do with AWS S3.